# Cosmos DB Query Works in Data Explorer But Not Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to run the following query against my cosmos db using Node.js.

```
const querySpec = {
    query: "SELECT * FROM Users u WHERE u.id = @email",
    parameters: [
        {
            name: "@email",
            value: "testuser@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
};

const { result: results } = client.database(databaseId).container(containerId).items.query(querySpec).toArray();
if (results.length == 0) {
    throw "No matching user";
} else if (results.length > 1) {
    throw "Account found";
}

const user = results[0];
console.log(user);
```

however I keep getting the error `TypeError: results is undefined`. The query works just fine in the data explorer. `databaseId` and `containerId` print the values I need them to if I use console.log.

Why might i be getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason you're getting this error is because `query` is an `async` method and you're not awaiting it. Can you try by changing the following line of code:

```
const { result: results } = client.database(databaseId).container(containerId).items.query(querySpec).toArray();
```

to:

```
const { result: results } = await client.database(databaseId).container(containerId).items.query(querySpec).toArray();
```

and see if that takes care of the issue.

Comment: I had to put `query` inside an `async` function as well then call it, but this worked. Thank you!