# Cannot call toArray() on QueryIterator using @azure/cosmos NPM

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I'm querying a local emulated Cosmos DB instance using the JS [@azure/cosmos](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js) package. I'm using version 3.1.1 (according to the package-lock.json) and I cannot call the `toArray()` function on the items for a container.

```
let databaseID = "database";
let collectionID = "collection";

const endpoint = "https://localhost:8081";
const key = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";
const client = new CosmosClient({ 
    endpoint, 
    key,
    agent: new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false
        }) 
});

let database = await client.databases.createIfNotExists({ id: databaseID });
let container = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({id: collectionID});

let items = container.items;
let readItems = items.readAll(); // crash
```

I get this crash:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: container.items.readAll(...).toArray is not a function
```

The [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/blob/216672a679ab389e5b341280eeacab1cab3691e4/samples/ItemManagement/app.js#L60) say I should be able to do this but I can't see the `toArray()` function in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/queryiterator?view=azure-node-latest#fetchall--). Interestingly `toArray()`is mentioned in the [documentdb documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/documentdb/queryiterator?view=azure-node-latest). Maybe this function hasn't be re-implemented, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Small follow up: an issue in the Azure Docs has been raised here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/37724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toArray() listed in the official github [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/blob/216672a679ab389e5b341280eeacab1cab3691e4/samples/ItemManagement/app.js#L107) clearly,so i think it is supported.

```
const { result: results } = await container.items.query(querySpec).toArray();

  if (results.length == 0) {
    throw "No items found matching";
  } else if (results.length > 1) {
    throw "More than 1 item found matching";
  }
```

I would suggest you putting the readAll() in the `async` function and use with `await`.(Follow this thread:[Cosmos DB Query Works in Data Explorer But Not Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56162063/cosmos-db-query-works-in-data-explorer-but-not-node-js))

My sample code:

```
const cosmos = require('@azure/cosmos');
const CosmosClient = cosmos.CosmosClient;

const endpoint = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";              // Add your endpoint
const key = "***";  // Add the masterkey of the endpoint
const client = new CosmosClient({ 
    endpoint, 
    key
});
const databaseId = "db";
const containerId = "coll";

async function run() {
    const { container, database } = await init();
    const querySpec = {
        query: "SELECT r.id,r._ts FROM root r"
    };
    const queryOptions  = {
        maxItemCount : -1
    }
      const { result: results } = await container.items.query(querySpec).toArray();

      if (results.length == 0) {
        throw "No items found matching";
      } else if (results.length > 1) {
        throw "More than 1 item found matching";
      }

}
async function init() {
    const { database } = await client.databases.createIfNotExists({ id: databaseId });
    const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({ id: containerId });
    return { database, container };
}

run().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

---

Update Answer:

I have to say sorry that i'm mislead by the MS official document.If i navigate to Query Documents github source code by the link in the MS document:

[image]

I could found such sample code :

[image]

However, that's the master branch! Not the latest 3.1.1 version! If i switch the version at the same above page,it shows 404:https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/blob/v3.1.1/samples/ItemManagement/app.js

More evidence, some comments:

[image]

So i believe that the @azure/cosmos V3 has been updated many things(such as toArray() method has been dropped),meanwhile the official link has not been updated.

Now,as you mentioned in your question,you could use fetchAll() to get the array of results:

```
const { resources: items }  = await container.items.query(querySpec).fetchAll();
console.log(items)
```

Output:

[image]

If any more concern,please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am still having trouble. Your sample code still results in the same problem: `TypeError: container.items.query(...).toArray is not a function`. I've uploaded my code to this [repo](https://github.com/lukestringer90/CosmosDB-JS).

Not sure why it would cause this specific problem but I am connecting to an emulated Cosmos DB running in a windows VM from my Mac.

Comment: @lukestringer90 Hi,i edited my answer ,please have a look.Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks for your update. That's cleared it up for me. The documentation is quite misleading but you got to the bottom of it.There is some mention of this API change in the [changelog](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/blob/1d02323eeb74ca410cc38ec7a052259c3e6b591b/changelog.md#simplified-queryiterator-api-238-316) but it looks like sample documentation has not caught up yet. I'm going to add an issue to the azure/cosmos repo to remind them.Thanks again!